# What is a default value parameter in Swift?

Tags: xcode, swift, ios8

```
func NSLocalizedString(key: String, tableName: String? = default, bundle: NSBundle = default, value: String = default, #comment: String) -> String
```

What is the meaning of `default`?

Comment: Hey, did you read https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Functions.html ?

Comment: yes, I did. I could not find a single mention of the default keyword in syntax. To be clear, I know how to specify default values for parameters. The default keyword is unexplained afaik.

Comment: It is not documented in the official Swift docs (as far as I know). But you can find it with a SO search for `[swift] "= default"` :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `default` word here is just a placehoder of the documentation for the real default value.

```
func NSLocalizedString(key: String, tableName: String? = default, bundle: NSBundle = default, value: String = default, #comment: String) -> String { ... }
```

could become

```
func NSLocalizedString(key: String, tableName: String? = "myDefaultTableName", bundle: NSBundle = NSBundle.mainBundle(), value: String = "myDefaultValue", #comment: String) -> String { ... }
```

Comment: Interesting, had no idea. Did you read it in the book? So it means “has a default value”.

Comment: Thank you. Could not find this info anywhere.